# Changing ACL of registry key, editing a value, then changing it back

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a Powershell script which changes a registry value that is *usually* owned by TrustedInstaller.  The basic workflow is:

1. Try to open the key for editing

   1. If this fails, try to open the key for permissions

      1. If this fails, try to open the key for taking ownership
      2. Backup the ACL with `if ($backupAcl -eq $null) { $backupAcl = $key.GetAccessControl(); }`
      3. Get a working copy of the ACL with `$acl = $key.GetAccessControl();`
      4. Set the owner with `$acl.SetOwner($me);`
      5. Open the key for permissions changes
   2. Backup the ACL with `if ($backupAcl -eq $null) { $backupAcl = $key.GetAccessControl(); }`
   3. Get a working copy of the ACL with `$acl = $key.GetAccessControl();`
   4. Apply the permissions with `$acl.AddAccessRule($rule); $acl.SetAccessControl($acl);`
   5. Open the key for editing
2. Change the values I need to change with `$key.SetValue(...)`
3. Revert any changes to permissions made earlier.

The code I am using to revert the permissions is as follows:

```
$key = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey($subKeyName, $regOpenMode, $regTakeOwnChangePerms);

Write-Host "Setting permissions to:"
Format-List -InputObject $aclBackup;

$key.SetAccessControl($aclBackup);

Write-Host "Permissions set to:"
Format-List -InputObject $key.GetAccessControl();

$key.Close();
```

...however, it never actually sets the ACL back to what it was.

Other than this, the script works fine -- the ACL is set to what it needs to be to change the values (so I know I *can* change the ACL) and the values themselves are changed (so I know I *have* changed the ACL).

But the reversion never takes.  No exceptions are raised -- it just never takes.

Why not?  And how can I revert the ACL to what it was when the script started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.  It seems you cannot re-use `ObjectSecurity` objects in this fashion, so I had to serialize the backup ACL using the `GetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm()` method and deserialize it back again using the `SetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm(...)` method.

Once I had done that, though, I got another error - *The security identifier is not allowed to be the owner of this object*.

I had to overcome this by requesting the `SeRestorePrivilege` system privilege, which I did with the `Enable-Privelege` function from http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/e718a560-2908-4b91-ad42-d392e7f8f1ad (a function I was already using to request the `SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege` needed to take ownership in the first place).

Once I had this privilege, I could overwrite the ACL with the deserialized one I had in my cache.

So, to backup the ACL:

```
if ($aclBackup -eq $null) { 
    $aclBackup = $key.GetAccessControl().GetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm(); 
}
```

And to restore it:

```
if (Enable-Privilege SeRestorePrivilege) {
    $acl = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity;
    $acl.SetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm($aclBackup, $aclIncludeAll);

    $key = $keyRoot.OpenSubKey($subKeyName, $regOpenMode, $regTakeOwnChangePerms);
    $key.SetAccessControl($acl);
    $key.Close();
}
```

Hopes this helps someone else in the future...

Comment: Thank you for your research.  I was having a problem setting the Owner back to TrustedInstaller and was getting the same error message.  Adding the SeRestorePrivilege fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're making modifications to an object in memory you will need to use the command `Set-ACL` to effect the change down to the actual file ACL.

Using Get ACL will read the access list from a registry key. I do not think you need this line.

```
$key = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey($subKeyName, $regOpenMode, $regTakeOwnChangePerms);
```

Try

```
$ACLobject = Get-ACL -Path $RegKey
$ACLObject |Set-ACL -Path $newRegKey
```

In between that you can manipulate the properties of $ACLobject any way you like.

Comment: Get-ACL won't let me get the ACL of an object I don't currently own.  I believe I have to use the above form to be able to take ownership.  I'm using a combination of http://powertoe.wordpress.com/2010/08/28/controlling-registry-acl-permissions-with-powershell/ and http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/e718a560-2908-4b91-ad42-d392e7f8f1ad for that.